# Python Graphics: Shape with function?

Tags: python

This assignment is asking me to draw a star function with four parameters. 
"center point of the star
size of the star
color of the lines of the star
window used to draw the star"

This is the example picture given: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urvt2.jpg

The hint: given the center point, you can clone it and move it to create each of the 5 points (ex:p1 = cenpt.clone(), p1.move(0,-0.85*size))

I misinterpreted the prompt in the first attempt and so far, I've mostly hard coded.

```
import graphics
def main():
window= graphics.GraphWin("x", 600, 400)
center = graphics.Point(300, 200)
center.setFill("red")
center.draw(window)
p1 = center.clone()
p1.move(0,-110)
p1.setFill('red')
p1.draw(window)
p2 = p1.clone()
p2.move(150, 250)
p2.setFill('red')
p2.draw(window)
line1 = graphics.Line(p1,p2)
line1.setFill("black")
line1.draw(window)
window.getMouse()
main()
```

obviously this doesn't work for function purposes. How could I modify this to work for given parameters in a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd define a function which given the coordinates and center points, would draw a point at the desired coordinates.

Something like this:

```
def makePoint (point, x, y):
    newpoint = point.clone()
    newpoint.move(x-300, y-200)
    newpoint.setfill('red')
    return newpoint
```

and then call that function once per point you want. If I wanted to use this to draw a point at coordinates 400, 500 I would call it like this: `makePoint(center, 400, 500).draw(window)`

You could also make one that just drew a new point at coordinates x and y instead of copying and moving a single point fairly easily, but it doesnt sound like thats what your instructor wants.